# Key being held down in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, game-physics, keydown

I am writing a game for class, and what the player does is uses "wasd" to swim away from a chasing shark. My code for movement is

```
Private Sub Form1_KeyDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventArgs) Handles Me.KeyDown
    Select Case e.KeyCode

        Case Keys.W
            If picSwimmer.Location.Y > -5 Then
                Loc = New Point(picSwimmer.Location.X, picSwimmer.Location.Y - 15)
                picSwimmer.Location = Loc
            End If
        Case Keys.S
            End If
            If picSwimmer.Location.Y < Me.Height Then
                Loc = New Point(picSwimmer.Location.X, picSwimmer.Location.Y + 15)
                picSwimmer.Location = Loc
            End If
```

(I have the same setup for a&d as well). My problem is that when you hold down one of the "wasd" keys, the image will move slightly then stop, then start moving fluidly after about a second. I think this is due to the amount of time it takes for VB to recognize that a key is being held down, rather than being clicked once. How would I make it so that VB will register that the key is being held down from the beginning, or shortens the time it takes to recognize the fact that it's being held down? Or anything that would make the movement smooth as soon as the key is pressed?

Comment: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.  No, it works the same way in the browser.  You need to record "swimmer is moving up" in KeyDown when you see the W key.  And "swimmer is not moving" in KeyUp, if still moving up.  And use a timer to make him move.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a Visual Basic setting it is a Windows Setting under `Keybaord Properties` you will need to shorten the `Repeat Delay Time` it will affect all applications on your computer.

[image]

Comment: @WillumMaguire You are welcome, just be aware that this will affect all of your applications as I mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

What you need is `GetAsyncKeyState` and a constantly running timer or thread that queries all keys and triggers the functions you need (one "step", which you must align with the interval of your timer, so long as the key is held down). This is also the only way (I know of) that you can process more keys at the same time.
And it is independent of focus (so maybe you should check if the right element has the focus).

Basics:

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Int32) As UShort
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.D)) Then Label1.Text = "RIGHT" Else Label1.Text = "-"
    If GetAsyncKeyState(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.W)) Then Label2.Text = "UP" Else Label2.Text = "-"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `GetAsyncKeyState` is much better in a situation where a second key may be pressed while the other is held.

**For example:**

Say that a player is:

- moving his tank forward by pressing and holding down the *Up key*
- and is shooting fire by pressing *space key*

In case you used the `Keydown` event, the tank will stop moving once the player press the *space key*.

To start moving again, he would have to release the arrow and re-press the *up key* after each fire.

```
Public Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal vKey As Int32) As UShort
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

If GetAsyncKeyState(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Up)) Then
    ''put here codes for moving the tank
End If

If GetAsyncKeyState(Convert.ToInt32(Keys.Space)) Then
    ''PUT HERE CODES FOR TANK FIRE
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello there! Thanks a ton for this answer! I have a query, is there a way to detect if any modifier key (Ctrl, Alt, Shift, Win, etc) is being held down, other than manually checking for each of them?